# Sentry is NOT reporting error inside Flutter

Tags: flutter, sentry

I have my Sentry setup like this:

```
void main() => runZonedGuarded(() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}, (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
  reportError(error, stackTrace);
});
```

and related functions

```
final SentryClient sentry = new SentryClient(dsn: '<my-dsn>');


Future<void> reportError(dynamic error, dynamic stackTrace) async {
  sentry.captureException(
    exception: error,
    stackTrace: stackTrace,
  );
}
```

I added `throw Exception("my-error")` inside a widget's build method, I can't see the error is showing on the Sentry web console.

I create a single file to throw exception and sentry capture, and I do see sentry is reporting the error.

Something must wrong with `runZonedGuarded`.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: For me it was a problem in the private network in which I used Sentry.

Answer (score 2):

After a number of Sentry setups that didn't seem to work right, I arrived at this one that works:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final sentry = Sentry.SentryClient(Sentry.SentryOptions(dsn: '[Add dsn URI here]'));

  runZonedGuarded(() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
      sentry.captureException(
        errorDetails.exception,
        stackTrace: errorDetails.stack,
      );
    };

    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    sentry.captureException(
      error,
      stackTrace: stackTrace,
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you must make the func async to send error to sentry console
2. be sure import this file for mobile app: 

   `import 'package:sentry/io_client.dart';`

   E.g:

main.dart

```
import 'package:sentry/io_client.dart';
final SentryClient sentry = new SentryClient(dsn: YOUR_DSN);

main() async {
  try {
    throw new StateError('This is a Dart exception.');
  } catch(error, stackTrace) {
    await sentry.captureException(
      exception: error,
      stackTrace: stackTrace,
    );
  }
}
```

HomeScreen

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async{

            throw new StateError('This is a Dart exception.');

          },
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in your sentry dashboard if you are using the free version and if the monthly quota hasnt been surpassed. If that is the case you will not receive any events.

Comment: I thought something had errored in our codebase at work but it was this. After a day of debugging this solved it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the way in release version it will send every exception, because in debug flutter doesn't catch every error that displays in the console, and to simplify that for you can use one of these packages :

- https://pub.dev/packages/catcher
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sentry